# YouTube app keeps pausing the video

Tags: video, youtube, pause

I am using a Nexus 5 D820 rooted stock Android 6.0.1 MOB30D.  The YouTube app version is 11.x and is the latest as I checked for the updates today.

The app pauses the video at random. I had to tap the play symbol at the center to start it to play.  This is not same as buffering as in buffering one would see a progress and the play symbol does not come up when the video is stopped.

- I tried this with my headsets and without headsets to rule out the
  press of headset button or something allied to cause the issue.
- I also tried this in 3G and in WiFi, both in high res and low res.
- I also tried this in offline mode.

In each and every case, the YouTube app pauses the video almost for once for every minute.  I do not want to switch over to another app and I cannot uninstall it as well.

Does anybody have any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Strange, I used it this morning without a problem on a Nexus 6. Not sure if I had the last update but almost positive, so I should rule out the app, but just in case, deactivate the app then reactivate it, this will uninstall every update then update it again. This might help.

Comment: I uninstalled the updates and went to play store and installed again.  Now the problem seems to be gone. I am just waiting for few more positive signs to declare this myself as a solution.

Comment: This is only my observation, but YouTube pauses the video if there's something taking the focus from the app. Usually it happens when Play Store is updating the apps in the background, but may happen with another apps with similar behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It might be. I am sure in my case there was no updates because I went to Play store to see whether there are any updates to YouTube app.  It does not happen always again. Yesterday out of 10 or so videos, two or three paused automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem is, it's because the phone thinks you keep plugging/unplugging the headphones. Try using another set of headphones and that should fix it.

I used the headphone that came with my PS4 and it caused the problem, it kept restarting but YouTube was still pausing until i changed the headphones then it went back to normal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that is a possibility, now I no longer face this issue. May be updates solved or change of broadband plans (speed) solved or change of phone might have solved.